# User settings, use EAV pattern or just add columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am using a MySQL database.

I have a user that can have many attributes, which I call settings. Each user has the exact same 50 settings. There will probably never be more than 2000 users in the system.

I can handle this in two approaches: add a column for each option, or use the EAV (entity attribute value) model.  User should be searchable by any of its settings.

---

**Adding columns only would look like this:**

```
id | name | pass   | color | beta  | .. 
----------------------------------------
1  | bob  | 94jf8d | red   | true  | ..
3  | sue  | fja928 | pink  | false | ..
```

---

**Using an EAV model would look like this:**

**user**

```
id | name | pass
------------------
1  | bob  | 94jf8d
3  | sue  | fja928
```

**setting**

```
id | key   | default_value
--------------------------
1  | color | red
2  | beta  | false
.. | ..    | ..
```

**user_setting**

```
id | user_id | setting_id | value
---------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1          | pink
2  | 1       | 2          | true
3  | 2       | 1          | green
4  | 2       | 2          | false
.. | ..      | ..         | ..
```

---

I realize that EAV adds a whole layer of complexity.  This includes having to deal with multiple joins to filter.  It just seems dirty to add 50 columns to the user table.

In the end, do you think I am better off adding columns, or moving to an EAV model?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect to have a lot of nulls in the settings or will most of the 50 columns contain data at most times?

Comment: There may be some nulls, maybe 30% of columns may end up having nulls.

Comment: If you know the 50 columns that each user has, and each user essential has (or could have) values for all 50, then they are attributes of the `user` entity.  Use columns in a single table rather than an EAV model.

Comment: I vote for columns, too.  But only because the "50" and "2000" are manageable numbers.